# How to edit edn file?

Tags: clojure, text-editor

I have an edn file created from a clojure app.  I'd like to edit the file directly to modify some values, but don't know how to do it easily.  I know that I can edit it in a text editor like sublime but the whole file is on the first line with no line breaks.  Is there some tool to break it down into fields, records, or key value pairs to make it easier, without having to learn clojure?

More detail:
The app in question is Logseq.  It maintains a file of all pages with a creation date and update date for each.  The creation date is not correct, so I was going to edit it directly.  Since I don't know clojure then I can't use pprint.  In sublime it is listed as:

```
[{:block/name "05-24-2021", :block/created-at 1621814400000, :block/updated-at 1621814400000} {:block/name "06-04-2021", :block/created-at 1622764800000, :block/updated-at 1622764800000} {:block/name "openings study", :block/created-at 1627400166344, :block/updated-at 1627400166344} {:block/name "progressive summarization", :block/created-at 1627587170901, :block/updated-at 1627587770818}
```

What I'd like it to look like for easier editing:

```
[{
:block/name "05-24-2021", :block/created-at 1621814400000, :block/updated-at 1621814400000} 
{:block/name "06-04-2021", :block/created-at 1622764800000, :block/updated-at 1622764800000} 
{:block/name "openings study", :block/created-at 1627400166344, :block/updated-at 1627400166344} 
{:block/name "progressive summarization", :block/created-at 1627587170901, :block/updated-at 1627587770818} 
etc.
```

Comment: You might be able to use the [`pprint`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/pprint) (pretty print) function to format it to make it more legible.

Comment: Have you tried switching your editor to use unix-linebreaks on that file? Or to put it different: are you sure the line breaks are missing and the file is just a data dump? Can you tell the application in question to "pretty print" the output? Can you share the name of the application?

Comment: @MeeBee, ...the other question is what features of the EDN format your specific file uses. If it only uses features that are also available in JSON, you can trivially convert it to JSON, edit it with widely-avaliable tools there, and then convert it back. But if all you want to do is add line breaks and such, `pprint` is your friend.

Comment: (Re: "since I don't know Clojure I can't use pprint" -- if you aren't willing to write some software, your question is off-topic here and should be asked at [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead; Stack Overflow is only for questions about software development. Whereas if you know Python or JavaScript and are looking to read/write/pretty-print EDN in one of those languages... well, searching for libraries isn't hard, and they _do_ exist)

Comment: ...see https://pypi.org/project/edn-format/ for an example of an EDN library for Python, since I mentioned the possibility (and note that, as documented in https://github.com/swaroopch/edn_format/blob/2a545f5969738cff7533eba611cd0ecafd65ab86/edn_format/edn_dump.py#L98-L117, it supports setting `indent=` to pretty-print your code). But really, what you're talking about is a one-liner in Clojure; it's not something that should scare someone away.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok that may work.  I do know python a bit, so may try that library.  And the one-liner of Clojure seems interesting.

Comment: `(clojure.pprint/pprint (clojure.edn/read *in*))` -- there's your one-liner. Granted, you'll want to `(require '[clojure.pprint] '[clojure.edn])` first (the Clojure-y equivalent of `import`ing libraries). I may add a version of that you can run with [`boot`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have [`boot`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot) installed in your PATH, you can pipe your code through the following script:

```clj
#!/usr/bin/env boot
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn]
         '[clojure.pprint :refer [pprint])

(defn -main [& args] (pprint (edn/read *in*)))
```

...as in (if the above is saved as `pprint-edn`):

```sh
pprint-edn <unformatted.edn >formatted.edn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [clojure
CLI](https://clojure.org/guides/getting_started) installed, you can run:

```sh
clojure -e "(do (require 'clojure.edn 'clojure.pprint) (clojure.pprint/pprint (clojure.edn/read *in*)))" < in.edn > out.edn
```